# Refresh jquery .click listeners in parental window to work with new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table which opens a popup window on click in a table cell and adds new table row in that table. And I want to add .click() listeners to these rows too. This is my HTML table

```
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%;">
<tr><th></th><th>Kompetence</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr>

<tr style=><td rowspan="2">My text</td>
<td>Some text</td><td class="hodnoceni 1">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 2">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 3">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 4">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 5">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>Another text</td><td class="hodnoceni 1" title="sum titl">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 2">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 3">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 4">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 5">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr class="newPartOfTable"><td rowspan="50">This is new part of table</td><td id="testId" class="testClass">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 1">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 2">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 3">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 4">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 5">&nbsp;</td><td class="hodnoceni 6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

and this is my javascript

```
var possibleInputs = ["T", "A", "Ž", " "];

var curValue;
$("#myTable .hodnoceni").click(function() {
    var level;
    var index = 0;
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    curValue = $(this).text();
    if(curValue == "T"){
        index = 1;
    }else if(curValue == "A"){
        index = 2;
    }else if(curValue == "Ž"){
        index = 3;
    }else{
        index = 0;
    }
    console.log("row index");
    console.log("total rows"+$("#kompetence tr").length);
    console.log("td clicked");
    var num = $(this).attr("class").match(/\d+/);
    $(this).text(possibleInputs[index]);
    console.log("Hodnoceni: "+num);
});
$(".newPartOfTable").click(function(){
    var rows = $("#kompetence tr").length;
    window.open("newPage.html?rows="+rows, "New popup", "width=600,height=300");
});
```

And this is javascript which adds new rows to the table(it's in the popup)

```
var table = window.opener.document.getElementById("myTable");
console.log(table);
var row = tabulka.insertRow(<%=paramTableRows %>);
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = "<%= paramTableRows %>";
    cell.className = "hodnoceni";
}
```

What I want to do is after I add new rows to the table I want them to have the existing .click() function binded to them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the classname u have added increments with every value that's where u have problem u need add the variable i to the class inorder to add the events to dynamically created rows/columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As new elements added by javascript are not part of DOM at DOM ready or page load so you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#myTable .hodnoceni", function() {
```

or

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ".hodnoceni", function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like

```
$("#myTable .hodnoceni").on('click', function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.on()`

just replace:

```
$("#myTable .hodnoceni").click(function() {
```

with:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myTable .hodnoceni', function() {
```

that will bind the click event for future dynamic dom elements as well, not only for those who were loaded with inital dom loading.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.hodnoceni', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...  
});
```

This will attach your event to any cell within the **#myTable** element, reducing the scope of having to check the whole document element tree and increasing efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery live has been deprecated on some versions. So better to use 'on'.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

It is applied to all the elements that is old or new in the DOM.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to look at the jquery live function

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()` http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc